# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "zumo" y "jugo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, comida

Escuchando la fantástica canción [*Lationamérica* de Calle 13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkFJE8ZdeG8&) que no me canso de poner me encuentro con esta estrofa (no sé si es estrofa, pues es algo rapeado):

> Soy el mar caribe que vigila las casitas
>   Haciendo rituales de agua bendita
>   El viento que peina mi cabello
>   Soy todos los santos que cuelgan de mi cuello
>   El **jugo** de mi lucha no es artificial
>   Porque el abono de mi tierra es natural.

Me recuerda esto lo que siempre me pasaba en Colombia: yo hablaba de *zumo de lulo* y me contestaban mencionando el *jugo*. Yo en España nunca he oído la palabra *jugo*, por lo que internalicé que las palabras serían sinónimas. Sin embargo, nunca es tarde para aclararse.

Buscando por internet encuentro [bastantes discusiones al respecto](https://www.google.es/search?q=diferencia%20zumo%20jugo). Por ejemplo, [en El campo de Elche hablan de](https://campodeelche.com/zumo-y-jugo-cual-es-la-diferencia/):

> - Zumo: es el líquido que obtenemos de exprimir hierbas, frutas, flores, y otras cosas semejantes.
> - Jugo: se considera jugo al zumo sacado por presión, destilación o cocción de vegetales o animales.

La definición parecería clara, pero lo que sigue lo complica:

> Dependiendo del país en el cual nos encontremos lo llamaremos de una forma o de otra, pero realmente nos estamos refiriendo al mismo tipo de producto, por ejemplo en países como Venezuela o Panamá, se utiliza la palabra jugo, ejemplo: me voy a tomar un *jugo de granada*, sin embargo en países como España  lo denominamos zumo, ejemplo: me voy a tomar un *zumo de granada*, como vemos en los dos casos estamos tomando lo mismo pero con distinto nombre.

Entonces la pregunta sería: ¿son realmente lo mismo? ¿En qué lugares se usa una u otra palabra?

Comment: Mi idea (no rigorosa) ear que si se raspa la cáscara de la naranja sería *zumo* (sabe amargo pero le da mucho sabor en ciertas recetas), y el líquido que se saca de la parte al interior sería *jugo*.

Comment: @aparente001 nótese que decimos _rig**u**rosa_ :)

Comment: ¡Para ser riguroso!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zumo es específico para frutas, mientras que Jugo es un término general para los líquidos extraídos de diferentes fuentes:

Zumos :

> Zumo de Limón
> Zumo de Naranja

Jugos

> Jugo de Limón
> Jugo de naranja
> Jugos gástricos
> Jugo de carne

En fin

> **Zumo de Naranja** y **Jugo de naranja** son lo mismo
>
> Pero no puedes tener **Zumo de carne** o **Zumos gástricos**

Comment: activa el corrector :P

Comment: hasta el corrector se equivoca... me quería cambiar "zumo" a "sumo"

Comment: Ese sería un error zumamente grande.